# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\Server\domains\localhost\test\class_search.php on line 163

Tags: php

Выдает ошибку

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\Server\domains\localhost\test\class_search.php on line 163
>   Line 163:

```
return '/'.$type.'/'.$r['res']->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)[0].'/'.$uid.'/';
```

Comment: Какая версия PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Прямое разыменование массива, возвращаемого в качестве результата вызова функции или метода стало возможным только с версии PHP 5.4. Я подозреваю, что версия у Вас ниже, поэтому Вы должны вначале сохранить в отдельную переменную результат, возвращаемый методом `fetch_array()`, а затем обратится к нулевому элементу полученного значения

```
$row = $r['res']->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
return '/'.$type.'/'.$row[0].'/'.$uid.'/';
```